# How can I scrape the images from a sub-reddit?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, reddit

Given a subreddit like /r/pics, how can I scrape all the images in Ruby?

I looked through Reddit's API, but there doesn't seem to be anything for this. But a site like "redditery" is already doing this - http://www.redditery.com/r/aww

Answer (score 1):

Check out [nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) it will be able to perform this task.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.reddit.com/r/aww"))
doc.css('div#siteTable').css('a').each {|x| puts x['href']}
```

That should output links to images (This code isn't tested but should be pretty close)